# how to set attribute value of div tag through ajax jquery

Tags: java, ajax, jquery

I want to set value of attribute 'data-rating'. It will use Ajax.

```
<div id="fixed_<s:property value="messageId"/>" **data-rating=**"<%=averageScore%>"></div> from ajax function though jquery that is as below :

`

$.ajax({
type : "POST",
cache:false,
url : '<s:url action="ratingStatus"/>',
dataType: "text",
data : 'score=' +score+'&messageId='+<s:property value="messageId"/>+'&categoryId='+<s:property value="categoryId"/>+'&threadId='+<s:property value="threadId"/>,
success : function(data) {
alert("inside Success...");

//here i want to set div attribute(data-rating) value from action class response that i have made...



//location.reload();

}
});`
```

Please help me if any one can....

Comment: How is your `response` look like ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
$("#fieldId").attr("data-rating","value want to set");
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$('#objectID').attr('data-rating', 'your value')
```

Comment: value of attribute had been changed but no effect until i refresh the jsp page. So it won't be work.

Answer (score 1):

Inside your success function

```
success : function(data) {

 $('#yourdivid').attr('data-rating','value from the response');
}
```

Comment: value of attribute had been changed but no effect until i refresh the jsp page. So it won't be work.